# Module that will display certain facebook content?

Tags: 6, social-network

I realize there are quite a bit of facebook possibilities main having to do with facebook account connections. What I'm interested though, is content (especially videos!) that is being put up in a facebook group that was created and having that display on the drupal site. Is there a module out there that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API requires you to "make an application" so it can assign you an API key you can use to connect things, like a drupal module, to your Facebook account. That is how it knows what content to pull from the Wall and let you manipulate it.

You might want to check out [Drupal for Facebook Module](http://drupal.org/project/fb) as it has a lot of facebook functionality you might be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this jquery plugin http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall to put an specific wall inside a block or node, and then you can improve the javascript code (I guess in *Parse feed data / wall* section of `jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js` file) to show only items with specific content, in this case, for example, a content using `uiVideoThumb` class (according my review `uiVideoThumb` is one class used to thumbns that link to videos).

specifically, in the js, in the section *Parse feed data / wall* line 81:

```
for(var k=0;k<max;k++){
```

you can add some lines to detect the specific content, for example:

```
var pattern=/uiVideoThumb/g;
var stringContent = JSON.stringify(data[k]);
if(stringContent.match(pattern)){
```

do not forget close this new `IF` declaration (near line 162).

Acording my test, only content with these condition is displayed.

one note: seems that the code has a Drupal´s module version http://drupal.org/project/fb_walls but not was clear to me how this module works over Drupal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer yes that looks quite promising I found that a while ago too. Fiddled with it a while until I realised I was going to have to spend a couple more hours figuring why and how I needed to 'create an app' if I wanted to get an identifier for my wall that I could use for the neosmart stuff.

Comment: Hi, If I understand well, you have problems with the sugestion? I have tested the suggestion against a wall with messages including video, and only is loaded messages with video thumbs. You must inspect, for example, the CSS ID or CLASS around the video to extract the respective value to parse. Appart of this and the suggestion, there is no other work to make.

Comment: I don't recall anything that has to do with a suggestion. Only thing I was stuck with has to do with an application ID of the facebook wall and the confusion (to this day) about how to retrieve it. Untill now, the answer still seems to 'create an application' which I still don't understand why that is.